# Php WHILE loops only find one element

Tags: php, while-loop, element

I got a problem with the following php code. It is supposed to list the items of a S3 bucket and find&delete files which contain a certain string in their filenames.
Problem is: only one file is deleted the others remain on the bucket after the execution of the script.
I can't find where the issue comes from so I ask you :/

```
$aS3Files = $s3->getBucket($bucketName); // list all elements in the bucket
$query = mysql_query("SELECT filename FROM prizes_media WHERE prize_id=" . $_POST["prizeId"]); // finds all filenames linked to the prize
while($media = mysql_fetch_array($query)){  
    // Find relevant files
    while ( list($cFilename, $rsFileData) = each($aS3Files) ) { // reformat the bucket list into a table and reads through it
        if(strpos($cFilename,$media['filename'])) {
            $s3->deleteObject($bucketName, $cFilename); // deletes all files that contain $media['filename'] in their filename
        }
    }
}

// 2. Delete DB entry
mysql_query("DELETE FROM prizes WHERE id=" . $_POST['prizeId'] ); // deletes the entry correponding to the prize in the DB (deletes media table in cascade)
```

Comment: Alright, the solution was to either:
1. add reset($aS3Files) cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304885/whilelistkey-value-eacharray-vs-foreacharray-as-key-value
2. replace "while list each" by foreach( $aS3Files as $cFilename => $rsFileData )

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting false negatives on your `if`, you should be using this:

```
if(strpos($cFilename,$media['filename']) !== FALSE) { ...
```

### Edit

Here is a different way to loop the bucket, based on the structure on your comment:

```
foreach($aS3Files as $filename => $filedata) {
    if(strpos($filename, $media['filename']) !== FALSE) {
       $s3->deleteObject($bucketName, $filename); // deletes all files that contain $media['filename'] in their filename
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it but I still have the same problem. I'm gonna try listing the bucket content inside the while loop even if it is heavy on resources...

Comment: It works when $aS3Files = $s3->getBucket($bucketName); is put inside the first loop. I'd prefer not having to do that as the bucket is small at the moment but that won't be the case in a few months :s

Comment: Something must be breaking one of the two loops early

Comment: Do you know another way of parsing $aS3Files, different from list($cFilename, $rsFileData) = each($aS3Files)?

Comment: $aS3Files format is as follow:

    Array ( [birdviews/0367b859cdb55b33d24e6849cd1d7b67.jpg] => Array ( [name] => birdviews/0367b859cdb55b33d24e6849cd1d7b67.jpg [time] => 1331220510 [size] => 177630 [hash] => 0367b859cdb55b33d24e6849cd1d7b67 ) [birdviews/0e11f6467e3a8c10334a322d03b17e7c.jpg] => Array ( [name] => birdviews/0e11f6467e3a8c10334a322d03b17e7c.jpg [time] => 1331220512 [size] => 133705 [hash] => 0e11f6467e3a8c10334a322d03b17e7c )