# Echo PHP array with index numbers

Tags: php, arrays

```
array(13) {
    [0]=> string(15) "TEST1"
    [1]=> string(12) "TEST2"
    [2]=> string(12) "TEST3"
    [3]=> string(12) "TEST4"
}
```

Output should look like this:

```
0 TEST1
1 TEST2
2 TEST3
...
```

I'm new to arrays so I'm searching for the cleanest way to do it. It worked with some counter variables but it was ugly as hell. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Take a look at [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), I'm sure you will get to your solution.

Comment: Do a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Not only foreach u can also use for loop

Comment: @devpro, how would you use a for loop?  I can only think it's useful for known integer-indexed arrays starting at 0, with sequential keys.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304885/whilelistkey-value-eacharray-vs-foreacharray-as-key-value

Comment: Yes it only useful with integer agreed @progrock.. I told in comments OP can also use for loop means only for OP requirement... not generaly. And I also post a commemt on my other mate answer love foreach dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " " . $value . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know that ($array as $key => $value) is possible. Thanks!

Comment: This is the most easy way love this.. u can also use for loop for it @jonas-knobloch

Comment: @JonasKnobloch, don't take this the wrong way, but if you didn't know this, you obviously didn't look up the PHP reference, which is the defactor reference to the language. You should spend some time here : http://www.php.net/docs.php  ( and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php )

Comment: Yeah. I'm new to PHP and should spend more time with the documentation. My question looks now more dumb every day for me. Have a nice day.